# PostgreSQL - NoSQL query ideas to select one node of JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, nosql, jsonb, marten

I have this JSON on my database:

```
  {
      "Id": 1,
      "Questions": [
        {
          "QuestionId": 6,
          "Description": "Question 1",
          "Alternatives": [
            {
              "Index": 1,
              "CorrectAnswer": false,
              "AlternativeId": 26,
              "QuestionId": 6,
              "Description": "Alternative one",
              "Selected": false
            },
            {
              "Index": 2,
              "CorrectAnswer": true,
              "AlternativeId": 27,
              "QuestionId": 6,
              "Description": "Alternative two",
              "Selected": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "QuestionId": 7,
          "Description": "Question 2",
          "Alternatives": [
            {
              "Index": 1,
              "CorrectAnswer": false,
              "AlternativeId": 26,
              "QuestionId": 6,
              "Description": "Alternative one",
              "Selected": false
            },
            {
              "Index": 2,
              "CorrectAnswer": true,
              "AlternativeId": 27,
              "QuestionId": 6,
              "Description": "Alternative two",
              "Selected": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

I can not get just ONE question in this document. I tried the following queries:

```
select data#>'{Questions}' from db.my_table
where (data #> '{Questions,0,QuestionId}')::numeric = 6;

SELECT data ->> 'Questions' AS Questions FROM db.my_table
WHERE (data -> 'Questions' ->> 'QuestionId')::numeric = 6;

SELECT data ->> 'Questions' AS Questions FROM db.my_table
WHERE data  -> 'Questions' ->> 'QuestionId' = '6'
```

What can I be doing wrong? I always get the return of 0 affected rows.

Documentation:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Every help is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's talk about each of your queries first:

```
select data#>'{Questions}' from db.my_table
where (data #> '{Questions,0,QuestionId}')::numeric = 6;
```

This actually fails (`ERROR:  cannot cast type json to numeric`). You can change the operator in the where clause to `#>>`, and it will no longer error -- `#>>` returns text, which can be cast to numeric. At that point the query will return your entire `Questions` array, however, rather than the specific question you want.

Why? Because all the questions are part of the same row.

`SELECT` returns rows, and its `WHERE` clause operates on rows. Since you have many values in a single row, you're going to have trouble conditionally extracting a json subobject with this approach.

The other two queries run successfully but produce no results:

```
SELECT data ->> 'Questions' AS Questions FROM db.my_table
WHERE (data -> 'Questions' ->> 'QuestionId')::numeric = 6;

SELECT data ->> 'Questions' AS Questions FROM db.my_table
WHERE data  -> 'Questions' ->> 'QuestionId' = '6'
```

In both cases, you're indexing a nonexistent field in your json blob. `Questions` is an array, so indexing it with a string doesn't work, but json is loose enough that it lets you try. In other words, the clause `WHERE data  -> 'Questions' ->> 'QuestionId' = '6'` simply doesn't match any rows.

The trick is to make each question into a row. That's a bit complicated, but not too hard to do.

First, look at the function [`json_array_elements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE), which seems like it should work -- it takes a json array and returns each element as a row with a single column (named "value"). At first glance, it seems like you should be able to do something of the form:

```
SELECT value FROM json_array_elements(...)
WHERE value ->> 'QuestionId'::numeric = 6;
```

Unfortunately, it's not quite so simple as that. Here's one query that works:

```
SELECT datatable.question
  FROM my_table,
    json_array_elements(my_table.data -> 'Questions') AS datatable(question)
 WHERE (question->>'QuestionId')::numeric = 6;
```

Okay, let's break that down a bit. Ultimately, it's returning the `question` field of the `datatable` table that we create using the `json_array_elements` call. `question` is a json object, and we filter to only return the objects where `QuestionID == 6`.

Note, though, that we're also selecting from `my_table`, because ultimately that's where the data comes from. In this case, we're making an unconstrained cartesian join between `my_table` and `datatable`. That's not good, and probably won't scale well. But it works for our current situation of only a few rows.

Hope that gives you a place to start.

Comment: Hey @jmelesky thanks for this response! But i have the following error:
`ERROR:  function json_array_elements(jsonb) does not exist
LINE 1: select json_array_elements(data -> 'Questions') from  db.m...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********´ when i run the last query (cartesian). My column is an jsonb...

Comment: If your column is jsonb, not json, then you should use the jsonb function instead of the json function. As the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) shows, that just means using `jsonb_array_elements`, instead of `json_array_elements`. In the future, providing more information about your schema in your question will help.

Comment: ! Thank you so much, its works now... I'll put some information about my schema so that you can see a possible "best solution". :)